# Strongly-typed view not initializing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a project request website and fleshing out a piece where employees working on a project can add estimates for the amount of time it will take to complete an area of a project. I wanted this page to post an arbitrary number of estimates back to the Edit action, but I'm missing something here.

In my View, I'm using the `Html.BeginCollectionItem` from [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) helper to assist with the AJAX-y stuff in `Html.RenderPartial("_WorkEstimateEditorRow", item);`.

**Edit:** I'm struggling with the AJAX parts of this right now -- I see the values come back in `Request.Form`, and the properties match up to my `WorkEstimate` class correctly, but even when I change my controller action to just accept an `IEnumerable<WorkEstimate>` estimates, it's null.

This is the output value of one row, using `Html.BeginCollectionItem`:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field EstimateId must be a number." data-val-required="The EstimateId field is required." id="estimates_d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220__EstimateId" name="estimates[d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220].EstimateId" value="0" type="hidden">
<input id="estimates_d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220__Estimator" name="estimates[d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220].Estimator" value="" type="hidden">
<span class="editor-label">
    <label for="estimates_d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220__WorkArea">Work Area</label>
</span>
<span class="editor-field">
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="estimates_d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220__WorkArea" name="estimates[d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220].WorkArea" value="" type="text">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="estimates[d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220].WorkArea" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</span>

<span class="editor-label">
    <label for="estimates_d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220__Hours">Hours</label>
</span>
<span class="editor-field">
    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Hours must be a number." data-val-required="The Hours field is required." id="estimates_d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220__Hours" name="estimates[d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220].Hours" value="0" type="number">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="estimates[d32afd89-987e-4d09-a847-abfc33dde220].Hours" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</span>
<a href="#" class="deleteRow">[x]</a>
<hr>
```

The `name` attribute is what comes across in `Request.Form` on the post action. I've also tried changing my Controller action so it receives an `IEnumerable<WorkEstimate>` without any change.

**Model**

```
public class EstimationManager
{
    public EstimationManager()
    {
        CurrentUser = new WebUser();
        Project = null;

        EstimationData = new WorkEstimateRepository();
        Estimates = new List<WorkEstimate>();
    }

    public EstimationManager(ApprovedProject project, WebUser currentUser)
        : this(project, currentUser, new WorkEstimateRepository())
    { }

    public EstimationManager(ApprovedProject project, WebUser currentUser, IWorkEstimateRepository repository)
    {
        Project = project;
        CurrentUser = currentUser;

        EstimationData = repository;

        Estimates = EstimationData.Get(Project);
    }

    IWorkEstimateRepository EstimationData { get; set; }

    public WebUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
    public ApprovedProject Project { get; set; }
    public List<WorkEstimate> Estimates { get; set; }

    public bool CurrentUserHasWorkerAccess
    {
        get
        {
            return CurrentUser != null
                && CurrentUser.AccessLevels.HasWorkerAccess
                && (Project == null || CurrentUser.AccessLevels.WorkerUnit == Project.CurrentWorkerUnit);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
public class EstimatesController : BaseSessionController
{
    private IProjectRepository _projects;
    private IWorkEstimateRepository _estimates;
    EstimationManager manager;

    public EstimatesController()
        : this(new WorkEstimateRepository(), new ProjectRepository())
    { }

    public EstimatesController(IWorkEstimateRepository estimates, IProjectRepository projects)
    {
        _estimates = estimates;
        _projects = projects;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Estimates/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ApprovedProject details = _projects.Get(id);
        manager = new EstimationManager(details, CurrentUser, _estimates);

        return View(manager);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Estimates/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        ApprovedProject details = _projects.Get(id);
        manager = new EstimationManager(details, CurrentUser, _estimates);

        if (TryUpdateModel(manager)
            && _estimates.TrySave(manager))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (WorkEstimate item in manager.Estimates)
            {
                foreach (RuleViolation currentViolation in item.GetRuleViolations())
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(item.WorkArea + currentViolation.PropertyName, currentViolation.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            return View(manager);
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model ProjectRequests.Web.Models.Project.Estimates.EstimationManager

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Estimate Details for " + Model.Project.Name;
}

<h2>Edit Estimate Details for @Model.Project.Name</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Estimation Manager</legend>
        <span id="editorRows">
            @foreach (ProjectRequests.Web.Models.Project.Estimates.WorkEstimate item in Model.Estimates)
            {
                if (Model.CurrentUser == item.Estimator)
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("_WorkEstimateEditorRow", item);
                }
                else
                {
                    Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item);
                }
            }
        </span>

        @if (Model.CurrentUserHasWorkerAccess)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add another estimate.", "BlankEstimateRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        }
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {
            $("#addItem").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $("#editorRows").append(html);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });

            $("#editorRows").on("click", ".deleteRow", function () {
                $(this).closest(".editorRow").remove();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

When my Edit action's signature is `public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)`, the view returns the appropriate data, but `TryUpdateModel` doesn't actually update the `Estimates` property. Conversely, `public ActionResult Edit(int id, EstimationManager newManager)` doesn't set `Estimates` either. The idea of manually sifting through the `FormCollection` to yank out the values from the page reeks of a big code smell, and this leaves me thinking that I should be handling this problem a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In order to get MVC to work with collections well, I found it's best to use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop in the view. When you are using the `Html` helper, access the values using an indexer in your expression, this will cause Razor to use that indexer in the name of the form control. On your controller, accept a collection (array for sure, you may be able to get away with `IEnumerable<>`) and it should work.

Since you are using a class as your model and not the collection directly, you may need to either use the `BindAttribute` on your action parameter to let MVC know that the request data will have a prefix, or use another class that has a property with the same name as the property in your `EstimationManager` class as the action parameter.

Just view source on the output from MVC once you start accessing via an indexer and I think the form names will help you understand what is going on.

Comment: The `foreach` part really isn't even getting executed -- I'm just handling the AJAX section right now (which isn't clear in the question). I've tried using the `BindAttribute` as you suggested, but I'm not having any luck. I'll update the question with some of the output from my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looping through the `Estimates` collection of the model, and taking the one `WorkEstimate` property's value from each `Estimate`, then either rendering a partial view with that `WorkEstimate` or making a label with it.

I'm guessing that since the view doesn't have specific `Estimate` items with indexes on it, the model binder can't figure out that they need to be bound into an `Estimates` collection, in the example where you're using `public ActionResult Edit(int id, EstimationManager newManager)`.

Also, apparently having the index values are important for collection items; it works better to use `for` rather than `foreach` and the indexers for collection items in a view, like so:

```cs
@for (int i = 0, i < Model.Estimates.Count; i++)
{
    Html.EditorFor(m => m.Estimates[i].WorkEstimate);
}
```

As a rough example.

Comment: I just updated the question -- I'll keep your advice in mind -- but right now, I'm having trouble getting the AJAX-added form data back to my controller.

Comment: @jwiscarson I also noticed you're not setting the `type` on the AJAX call. The default for `type` is GET. I think you want to do a POST there though, right? Maybe it's hitting the wrong controller action (GET instead of POST).

Comment: No, I have a partial action in my controller, which I missed when I pasted in my code, that returns a `new WorkEstimate()` to the the partial view, and the partial view is then appended to the table.